# Apache Ant won't do math

Tags: xml, ant, build-automation

I'm using distributed source to work on a project in Java, and the source has to be built using a custom Ant script in order to work properly. The problem is, when I run the script, I get

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\[path]\autobuild.xml:47: Only 1 operation can be specified
```

Lines 47-59 read:

```
<math result="months" datatype="int">
    <op op="-">
        <op op="+">
            <num value="${month}"/>

            <op op="*">
                <num value="${year}"/>
                <num value="12"/>
            </op >
        </op>
        <num value="24097"/>
    </op>
</math>
```

I've tried googling the error phrase and the only result is the [Ant source of MathTask.java](http://ant-contrib.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0~b3plus-psvn177-3/MathTask_8java_source.html) where it shows that this is what should happen if the operation is null. I tried changing the code along the lines of:

```
<op type="-">
```

or

```
<op op="subtract">
```

but these produced the same error. I changed it instead to:

```
<subtract>
```

and now there is no error but the result is always zero.
I've also tried reducing the math stanza to having just one operation:

```
<math result="months" datatype="int">
    <op op="subtract">
        <num value="27940"/>
        <num value="24123"/>
    </op>
</math>
```

but the problem remains.

I'm completely at a loss. Does anyone have any clue what's going on here? I'm using the newest version of Ant... ${month} and ${year} are properly set (I've also tested with hardcoded numbers and it still doesn't work).

Thanks!

Comment: What is the java runtime version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an embedded scripting language like [Jython](http://dbmstools.sourceforge.net/docs/jythontask.html) or [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) instead, which might be more readable and easier to manipulate than XML.

```
<groovy>
month = Integer.valueOf(properties["month"])
year = Integer.valueOf(properties["year"])

properties["months"] = 24097 - ((year * 12) + month)
</groovy>
```

Comment: How do I deploy such a program written in ant? If only there was a build system to compile, test, and distribute my programs written in groovy-in-ant ...

Comment: The above example uses the Ant Groovy task. There's nothing to compile, and it's easier to read, maintain, and test than math-in-xml...

Comment: just put the jar file in your classpath according to the list of ANT dependencies in ANT's official manual.

Comment: This worked, although I had to change the first two groovy lines to `Integer.valueOf(properties["month"])` ... I was hoping for a fix that would let me continue to use the same build.xml file that everyone else is using... because what if they change something? This is an ongoing project.

Comment: Thanks though. If I don't get another answer within a day, I'll accept this one.

Comment: @MalcolmMcC Yes, I didn't actually test that... I should have figured that the properties were strings. Is there a reason you can't include this in the main build file? In general something like this is going to be more maintainable than programming in XML, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with this piece of code. The funny thing is that most of the time it does work. The error occured about every 5th time I ran my build script.

```
<math datatype="int" result="rndNum">
    <op op="+">
        <num value="42000" />
        <op op="*">
           <num value="1000"/>
           <op op="random"/>
        </op>               
    </op>
</math>
```

I removed the *datatype* attribute from the math task and put it in the first op.

```
<math result="rndNum">
    <op datatype="int" op="+">
        <num value="42000" />
        <op op="*">
           <num value="1000"/>
           <op op="random"/>
        </op>               
    </op>
</math>
```

So far it works. Lets see how long :) I'll remove my answer if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

You need no additional ant tasks or additional scripting languages, just use the builtin javascript scripting engine java ships with (since jdk 1.6, Sun's own implementation based on rhino 1.6R2) and put in a macrodef for resuse, i.e. :

```
<project>
  <property name="foo" value="22"/>
  <echo>$${foo} => ${foo}</echo>

  <!-- create macrodef -->
  <macrodef name="math">
   <attribute name="operation"/>
   <attribute name="operator1"/>
   <attribute name="operator2"/>
   <attribute name="result"/>
   <sequential>
    <script language="javascript">
     tmp = 0;
     switch ("@{operation}")
     {
      case "+" :
       tmp = parseInt("@{operator1}") + parseInt("@{operator2}");
       break;
      case "-" :
       tmp = parseInt("@{operator1}") - parseInt("@{operator2}");
       break;
      case "*" :
       tmp = parseInt("@{operator1}") * parseInt("@{operator2}");
       break;
      case "/" :
       tmp = parseInt("@{operator1}") / parseInt("@{operator2}");
       break;
     }
     project.setProperty("@{result}", tmp);
    </script>
   </sequential>
 </macrodef>

  <!-- create new properties -->
  <math operation="/" operator1="${foo}" operator2="11" result="foooo"/>
  <math operation="+" operator1="${foo}" operator2="21" result="fooo"/>
  <!-- overwrite existing property foo -->
  <math operation="+" operator1="${foo}" operator2="1" result="foo"/>
  <echo>
  create    => $${fooo} => ${fooo}
  create    => $${foooo} => ${foooo}
  overwrite => $${foo}  => ${foo}
  </echo> 
</project>
```

If you need to overwrite an existing userproperty (= those properties defined on commandline via ant -f foobar.xml -Dmyuserproperty=foo ...) you have to use the method

```
project.setUserProperty()
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Although it may not work in the future: there's a deprecation warning. ```[script] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release```